# Is there a quicker way to download HTML/XML documents?

Tags: python, download

I am building a financial application that is using the [ystockquote module](http://goldb.org/ystockquote.html) to get the price of a stock at any given time.

The problem that I have encountered is that it will take me about a second or two to get the price of the stock. I need to reduce this time, greatly.

I understand that I should get a faster internet connection, but other than that, is there anyway to speed up the time it take Python to download an HTML/XML document off the internet?

Comment: Please provide the code you're using to download a document.

Answer (score 2):

If you can stand to have the connection open and have reasonably short durations between accesses then use a module with keepalive, such as urlgrabber.

Comment: The [documentation for `urlgrabber.keepalive`](http://urlgrabber.baseurl.org/help/urlgrabber.keepalive.html) shows you how to set that up; you should be able to just change the `ystockquote`'s `import urllib` to that example and change the `urllib.urlopen` to `urllib2.urlopen` in `__request`, and that should work.